# How to Convert tdms file to text or csv in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Here i tried nptdms module but giving error

```
tdms_file = TdmsFile.as_dataframe('file.tdms',time_index=False, absolute_time=False, scaled_data=True)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

please anyone have idea to convert tdms file csv or text file ,
here i don't know what is inside the file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the filepath and read in the actual file.  Right now you are trying to read in the string 'file.tdms' which is merely 9 letters -- so you get the 'str' object error.  Find the actual filepath for the file.tdms and you should be fine.  It could look something like this:

```
filepath = '/home/x/y/file.tdms'
tdms_file = TdmsFile.as_dataframe(filepath,time_index=False, absolute_time=False, scaled_data=True)
```